# lisp different length two list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm having difficulties with two lists of different lengths.

`(f '(8 1 2 3 23 12) '(2 9 4 6))` should return `(1 2 3 4 6 8 9 12 23)`

This is my trying code.

```
(defun f (lst lst2)
  (cond ((or(null lst) (null lst2)) 0)
  (t (sort (cons (first lst) (cons (first lst2) (f (rest lst) (rest lst2)))) #'<))))
```

Plus, Can you handle duplicates in lisp?

I will appreciated any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can easily be done with standard functions. To make one list out of two you use [`append`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_append.htm#append), however the last argument is shared so I copy it with [`copy-list`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cp_lis.htm#copy-list) since [`stable-sort`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_sort_.htm#stable-sort) is destructive. [`delete-duplicates`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_dup.htm) removes the duplicates in the resulting list.

```
(defun f (lst1 lst2)
  (delete-duplicates (stable-sort (append lst1 (copy-list lst2)) #'<))))

(f '(8 1 2 3 23 12) '(2 9 4 6))
; ==> (1 2 3 4 6 8 9 12 23)
```

Comment: Would you consider it more _efficient_ to first remove the duplicates and than sort the possibly shorter list?

Comment: +1, but two things: (1) why a stable sort in that case? numbers that are equal w.r.t. the partial order `<`  cannot be distinguished from each other. (Also, duplicates are eventually removed). (2) you can safely use `delete-duplicates`.

Comment: @coredump  `stable-sort` does the right thing always. If you only use one sorting function this is the one. I agree on `delete-duplicates`

Comment: @MartinBuchmann Yes, but it's a micro optimization. With a performance issue where you are certain this is the place that needs fixing you can make it faster by making it one pass, but the result is still O(n logn) because of the sorting. To fix that further you need to change the specifications, which happens often. Ie. perhaps you only were interested in the 3 lowest values... Then you can do it `O(n)` and you don't have to delete, sort or append. Just iterate and keep the 3 lowest values (in order).

Comment: @Sylwester I understand. My view is that if you always use stable-sort, it becomes harder to know, when reading code, if you actually need stability or not. Sometimes it is easy: elements are obtained from operations which do not give any guarantee (like the order by which elements are iterated from a hash-table). Stable sorting such collections is meaningless (and costly). Besides, I often do not need such guarantees in the first place: either I need to enforce the order is total, in which case stability has no incidence, or I do not care about order among equivalent values.

Comment: @coredump In most languages the provided sorting function is stable and in the languages that don't it's [a constant headache](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+stable+sort). `sort` in CL will be stable in most CL implementations so the second you do a mistake it might pass all tests with flying colors and still not be portable.

Comment: @Sylwester The actual sorting bugs I saw were always due to the comparison function: the tie-breaking comparison was in fact not total; another was a preorder (both X<Y and Y<X) and added dependencies during the sort; in those cases the traversal order was an implicit parameter (you have either A < B, or B < A, depending on implementation details). I would have needed less stability to detect those bugs (i.e. shuffle the sequence first). As you said, you can have latent bugs if the sort is stable and hides some comparison bug. But I use stable-sort if there is any chance the caller might care.